# c# How to show name and insert values (name's ID ) from combobox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Thank you guys in advance. I'am new user in c# Windows Forms.

I have a table with id's and name

```
ID  | Name
---------------
1   | Lion
2   | Tiger
3   | Crocodile
```

If I want to display from a table to combobox I did like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Insert_update_delete_nr2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"CONNECTION_STRING");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                con.Open();

                string query = "select * from info";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (dr.Read())//while true
                {

                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());//loading values into combo
                }

                cmd.CommandText = "insert into info3 (name, name_id) values ('"+textBox1.Text+"', '" + comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString()) + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.Clone();
                con.Close();

        }

        private void loadlist()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            listBox3.Items.Clear();
            con.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "select * from info3";
             dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                    listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1]).ToString();
                    listBox3.Items.Add(dr[3].ToString());


                }
            }
            con.Close();


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       // con.Open();
        FillDropDownList(string SQL, ComboBox comboBox1);// This giving me error.
        // How should I call this FillDropDownlist function? The parameters which are they?
        cmd.Connection = con;
        listBox3.Visible = false;

        loadlist();

    }



    }
}
```

And it's trying inserting what is showing in combobox which it's name, not id's.

in PHP it would be like the following:

```
$sql =  " SELECT * FROM info ";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    print '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
```

That would insert id's and showing names. But How should I do in c#?
Thank you again for your time!

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: SLaks: Sorry, it's Windows Forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you are seeking:

Load your combo box with something like THIS (I can't test this right now, so I may have made some typo's or minor syntax errors):

****UPDATED: Ok. That is the LAST time I try to answer a question "on the go" when I'm in a rush. My original code was rife with issues and stupid typos. My sincere apologies! The following code includes a very basic version of everything you are trying to do. You may need to adapt it to suit your needs.

Some suggestions:

A. Place your connection and command in the using blocks, as shown.

B. Instead of hard-coding your connection string in your code, use the Properties.Settings designer in the Solutions Explorer (off to the left) and create a central reference for your connection string. Then reference it in code like shown.

The following performs the basic functionality you are trying to achieve, and runs on my machine:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        this.FillDropDownList();
    }


    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SaveComboBoxContent();
    }


    public void FillDropDownList()
    {
        string SQL = "SELECT id, name FROM info ORDER BY name";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Set the connection string in the Solutions Explorer/Properties/Settings object (double-click)
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString))
        {
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();

                try
                {
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    // Do some logging or something. 
                    MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data. DETAIL: " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        // UPDATED - The .ValueMember and .DisplayMember properties 
        // refer to the string name of the field (oops!):
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    }


    public void SaveComboBoxContent()
    {
        string SQL = "INSERT INTO info2 (name_id) VALUES (@name_id)";

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString))
        {
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_id", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
                cn.Open();

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    // Do some logging or something. 
                    MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data. DETAIL: " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you XIVSolions, Itsme and others. Today I'am very sick and I will try tommorow.

Comment: In other words, you have asked four questions, but have accepted answers on only one of them. This tells people that when they take the time to answer your question, your are unlikely to acknowledge their efforts. Of course, you can only accept ONE answer. But the gamification here on SO is part of the fun, and the motivation.

Comment: I see...thank you XIVSolutions. I will do that. It's giving me some erros your answer. in public void FillDropDownList(string Query, ComboBox DropDownName)

Comment: I see...thank you XIVSolutions. I will do that. It's giving me some erros your answer. in FillDropDownList(string Query, ComboBox DropDownName) it's gave me error at DropDownName.ValueMember = dt["id"];
    DropDownName.DisplayMember = dt["name"]; . it says cannnot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'system.Data.DataTable' then in public void SaveComboBoxContent() on  try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery; // here givs me error like 'only assigment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statment'

Comment: Can you edit your post and show me your current code? Oh, btw, I screwed up. In the code I posted, `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery;` should be `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`  (remember my caveat about not being able to test the code at the time I posted it?) - see edited code.

Comment: Ahh. I see the problem. I forgot to change the control name to match yours. See modified code. Where your code was using the name `comboBox1` for the control, mine had `DropDownList` (I had copies the basic code from a source file I had on my local drive, then modified to answer your question). Apologies for the confusion - it SHOULD work now, short of any minor typo's. Let me know if you still have difficulties . . .).

Comment: Thank you very much XIVSolution, but stil the same problem with DropDownName.ValueMember = dt["id"]; DropDownName.DisplayMember = dt["name"]; . it says cannnot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'system.Data.DataTable'. SaveComboBoxContent() is now fixed. Now I have edited the hole code and I hope you will find the problem. I don't know why it didnt apply indexing with []. Thank you again. See edited code.

Comment: Achhh! I see my other error. Change to the following (and see updated code in my answer): `comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";` and `comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";`. This is what I get for trying to answer without the code editor!

Comment: Thank you sir, Now there is no error, but I get errors when I want to use them.  (see edited). I call function FillDropDownList(string Query, ComboBox DropDownName) in my private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) with parameters SQL and comboBox1 but it gavs me error. Where shall I call your functions and how? See edited at private void Form_load..... thank you again.

Comment: @JonasWillander - OK. I made a total mess out of that answer when I first posted. See the update. You should be able to paste directly into your form and use it, with the exception of resetting your connection string (see the update notes. My sincere apologies for the crazy, typo-ridden original answer.

Comment: WAAAWWWWWWW, Perfekt, My god.. I don't know how to thank you.. now it's working. You can't imagine how happy am'I. i realy admire you becouse of your commitment your welling to help without giving up. You are realy nice person. But compair with PHP I can see that C# is very complicated language compair PHP. PHP is very easy but I have intresst about c# too. I don't know how should I start to become like you. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Glad it worked. Learning a new language and syntax is challenging. I strongly recommend pursuing it, though. Once you get used to it, you find it becomes easier. Again, my apologies for the many screw-ups. This is actually fairly trivial code, which should have been posted correctly in my first post!

Comment: Hello Sir! May I ask you similar question?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of adding the name string to the combobox, you could add a custom type, instead:

```
class Animal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Create an object of that type for each entry (`var animal = new Animal { ID = (int)dr[0], Name = (string)dr[1] };`), add the object to the combobox. Then when you go to retrieve it, simply cast the item to an Animal type and grab the ID.

```
var animal = (Animal)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```