# i can't get value from combobox

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a combobox in form5 and the script is below.

```cs
string sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `status`='1' AND `jml_stock`>'0'";
string sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `pelanggan`";
        
MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(con);
mcon.Open();

MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(sql, mcon);

MySqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    string id_stock = dr["id_stock"].ToString();
    string nama = dr["nama_produk"].ToString();
    barang.Items.Add(nama);
    barang.ValueMember = id_stock;
    barang.DisplayMember = nama;
}

mcon.Close();
```

I want to retrieve data from the combobox above using this script.

```
id_stock = barang.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

but I get an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

What do you think did I do wrong?

Comment: This is winforms or? You misunderstood the meaning of `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`; these should be the names to two properties of the object you added to the Items collection.

Comment: yeah this is winform. idk, i google and get like that. actually it works for last index in combobox, but i cant get value member of index 0. do you have any reference for problem like that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248303/c-sharp-how-to-show-name-and-insert-values-names-id-from-combobox-in-c-sharp

Comment: thanks, Klaus, your reference is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code

```
  barang.ValueMember = "id_stock";
    barang.DisplayMember = "nama_produk";
```

Also you can see following article.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/combobox-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: when I try what I get just display member. I want to get the value of Combobox. do you have any reference ?

Comment: You can try this article https://stackoverflow.com/a/52044364/14882929